# How to handle nameof(this) to report class name

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

I'd like to use the following C#6 code

```
var joe = new Self();
Console.WriteLine(joe);
```

... and get the following output:

> joe

The following attempt

```
class Self {
  public string Name { get; set; } = nameof(this);
  public override string ToString() {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

fails as `nameof` cannot be applied to `this`. Is it there a workaround for this problem?

**EDIT**. The scenario I'm working with assures that no two references point to the same `Self` object.

Comment: I don't think so. Consider `var joe = new Self(); var jack = joe;`. Should `Name` return `"joe"`, `"jack"`, or both?

Comment: What's wrong with `nameof(joe)`

Comment: You can learn some usages of nameof(..) from this post : http://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/C-sharp-6-most-exciting-features-9

Comment: Unicity of different instances of the same class is achieved through `ReferenceEquals`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, maybe with a custom implementation (for example `Equals` can check an `Id` field/property on the two inspected instances). Your idea of using `nameof` to achieve such a goal is very strange...

Comment: Why can't we use `this.GetType().Name`?

Answer (score 21):

No, `nameof` is designed to refer to the compile-time name of the member you're referring to. If you want an object to have a `Name` property as part of its state, that is independent of how you *get* to the `Name` property - as Frédéric Hamidi says, there could be multiple variables (or none) referring to the same object. Basically you need to differentiate between an object and a variable which happens to refer to that object.

However, if you have a constructor to specify the name, you could then use a couple of tricks to make it easier to get the right name:

```
class Self
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Self([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
class Foo
{
    private Self me = new Self(); // Equivalent to new Self("me")

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Can't use the default here, as it would be "SomeMethod".
        // But we can use nameof...
        var joe = new Self(nameof(joe));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can use the following method:

```
    class Self
    {
       public override string ToString()
       {
            return this.GetType().Name;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `nameof` on the variable itself:

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(joe));
```

[Here](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayeVAE4wAVn1QwAvDABEBRdpyy5imAtQhgRZJpgQq6VHwBmY1agmGjbenwgg+RKgAdADqCmBoADKQqGJmFlYeMmwAvtgpQAA)'s a working example using the current Roslyn version

Answer (score 1):

The idea for `nameof` is to make things type safe for specifying program elements during runtime but with compile time type safety checking.

One should *atomize* what one wants to display. For example in my error messages I include the pertinent information of the class name and the method as such and its checked, so if I change any of the names they are caught as a compile time error:

```
class Operation
{
  public void Execute()
  { 
    try { ... }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.Writeline($"{nameof(Operation)}.{nameof(Execute)} has encountered exception:{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}" );
    }
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
Operation.Excecute has exception:
...
```

---

With that said you should override `ToString()` and report the class name as such

```
public override string ToString() { return nameof(Self); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create an internal constant for it when dealing with long class names:

```
private const string SomeConst = nameof(Self);
```

Then you can use that in your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(SomeConst);
```